# django telegram вывод кнопок

Tags: django, telegram

Добрый день. Подскажите что не так.

Написал простого echo-bot. Использую Django на домене с ssl. Создал webhook, все работает по следующей схеме ниже.

смотрю документацию, [вот пример с выводм кнопок](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#message-has-a-flavor)

не могу понять как его внедрить в свой код. В примере используется

> MessageLoop().run_as_thread()

в который передается список функций обработчиков, но попытка его использовать не к чему не привела.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^bot/(?P<bot_token>.+)/$', views.CommandReceiveView.as_view(), name='command'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
import json, telepot
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponseBadRequest, JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.conf import settings
TelegramBot = telepot.Bot(settings.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)


class CommandReceiveView(View):
    def post(self, request, bot_token):
        if bot_token != settings.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Invalid token')

        raw = request.body.decode('utf-8')

        try:
            payload = json.loads(raw)
        except ValueError:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request body')

        chat_id = payload['message']['chat']['id']
        cmd = payload['message'].get('text')

        TelegramBot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'echo: {}'.format(cmd))
        return JsonResponse({}, status=200)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CommandReceiveView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```